# How to extract links from a text file?

Tags: bash, grep

Suppose there is a text file test.txt. It contains text and links to resources such as `https://example.com/kqodbjcuic49w95rofwjue`. How can I extract only the list of these links from there? (preferably via bash, but not required)

I tried this solution:

```
sed 's/^.*href="\([^"]*\).*$/\1/'
```

But it didn't help me.

Comment: Can you show sample data from `test.txt` and your expected output

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -o "/((?:(?:http|ftp|ws)s?|sftp):\/\/?)?([^:\/\s.#?]+\.[^:\/\s#?]+|localhost)(:\d+)?((?:\/\w+)*\/)?([\w\-.]+[^#?\s]+)?([^#]+)?(#[\w-]*)?/gm" test.txt
```

will display all URLs inside the file.

(The regex comes from BSimjoo's link)

Grep text files guide at https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/how-to-grep-for-text-in-files/

Comment: `grep: Invalid range end`